# How to install Octave on Windows 10? Do I need to unzip the folder that comes along?

Tags: windows, installation, octave

I am trying to install Octave on win 10. But the download site included multiple files for each version like this:
[image: Check 64 bit 4.2.1 version]

As a result, I downloaded all and started unzipping the folder. It takes forever to download. However, the installer finished running and installation is done. What do I do? And moreover, why is windows unzipper so slow? The speed is only 1 kbps.

Comment: These zip files are different versions of octave. You need to download only one, for example, `octave-4.2.1-w64.zip` (or `-w32` if you have 32-bit windows), unzip it and install. Then launch octave from the start menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download octave from here:

[Official Octave site](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/download.html)

If you download Zip or 7z file, you first need to extract it.
Afterward, follow the step, to begin with, octave.

[image: Step-1: Create shortcut of "octave.vbs"]

[image: Step-2: Move it to your desired location(Here I moved it to where a file is extracted).]

[image: Step-3: Right-click on a shortcut and click on Properties.]

[image: Step-4: Finally add "--force-gui"(without quote) in Target field and click OK, That's it. Now open shortcut and you'll be able to run Octave in GUI.]

Answer (score 0):

The 4.2.1 comes in w32 and w64 architecture, both as installer and "portable" zip only.

Since you are using windoze 10 I guess you have fairly recent hardware (both your PC the last 5 years) and you have a 64bit CPU architecture. Furthermore I guess you want a typical installer like most windoze user are used to.

TL;DR: Download **octave-4.2.1-w64-installer.exe**
double click it in your file explorer and follow the installation instructions. After that click the icon in the start-menu

Comment: further to the `.zip` issue recently, this is further evidence that a proper "download" page with instructions is sorely needed